# SQL Query DIFFDATE Returns Invalid Identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to display the difference in days between 2 columns using diffdate, using the following code:

```
SELECT
  ORDERS.ORDERID,
  ORDERS.CUSTOMERID,
  ORDERS.ORDERDATE,
  ORDERS.SHIPDATE,
  DATEDIFF ( DAY, ORDERS.ORDERDATE, ORDERS.SHIPDATE)
FROM
  ORDERS
```

But it comes out with Invalid Identifier - Where am I going wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Where in the Oracle manual did you find the function `datediff()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Oracle, you can just subtract two days to get the difference:

```
SELECT ORDERS.ORDERID,
       ORDERS.CUSTOMERID,
       ORDERS.ORDERDATE,
       ORDERS.SHIPDATE,
       (ORDERS.SHIPDATE - ORDERS.ORDERDATE)
FROM ORDERS;
```

Your code uses a SQL Server function that is not defined in Oracle.

If the values have time components that you don't want:

```
SELECT ORDERS.ORDERID,
       ORDERS.CUSTOMERID,
       ORDERS.ORDERDATE,
       ORDERS.SHIPDATE,
       TRUNC(ORDERS.SHIPDATE) - TRUNC(ORDERS.ORDERDATE)
FROM ORDERS;
```

Comment: Perfect thank you, but how do I limit this to whole numbers?

Comment: i thought oralce don't have datediff too, always would use - to get the result and use convert to get the days. but i checked online and get this https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/1212/gg-winux/GWURF/column_conversion_functions011.htm#GWURF780. never used it. don't know if it worked

Comment: @MattJohnson . . . You can truncate the dates columns so they have no time component.  Or truncate the result after the subtraction.

Comment: Can you provide a line example?

Comment: Perfect result! Thank you!