# Need Simple way to Find Duration between start and end date

Tags: sql, oracle, duration

I am looking for the simplest way to find the time duration between start and end time data in the database. [Actual and expected date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umWQF.png)

Tried "DATEDIFF" but getting this error "ORA-00904: "DATEDIFF": invalid identifier"
Formate used: DATEDIFF(time, START_TIME, END_TIME) AS DURATION

Need help in fixing it, PFA to see the actual START_TIME & END_TIME, I am looking for the duration of those two in a separate column

Comment: Are you using Oracle?
Here's where you can find more help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143911/sql-query-diffdate-returns-invalid-identifier

Comment: I am trying to use like this 
(END_TIME - START_TIME) AS DURATION

But still getting [Error] : ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: what is the data type of start_time and end_time

Comment: Where in [the Oracle manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/index.html) did you find the `datediff()` function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below in Oracle to get the value in the requested format

```
create or replace function DATEDIFF_IN_ORC(P_START_TIME IN VARCHAR2, P_END_TIME IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2 
    IS
    START_TIME DATE;
    END_TIME DATE;
    L_RESULT VARCHAR2(100);
    BEGIN
    START_TIME:=TO_DATE(P_START_TIME,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
    END_TIME:=TO_DATE(P_END_TIME,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');

          select ltrim(lpad(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(24*(end_time-start_time)) ) || TO_CHAR(TRUNC(end_time) + 
          (end_time-start_time) , ':MI:SS' ) , 12, ' ')) INTO L_RESULT from dual;

     return l_result;
     END;
```

Call like the below

```
    select DATEDIFF_IN_ORC(START_TIME,END_TIME) from dual;
```

Output:-

```
     0:02:34
```